# Store and print shortest path using BFS

Tags: c++, queue

I'm using breadth-first-search (so a queue) to get from a position of X1.X2.X3.X4.X5 (e.g., 0.0.0.3.0) to 0.0.0.0.0. I'm able to reach the goal. I just need to print the shortest path to it. I think keeping track of a pointer to the parent will work. But, I'm having lots of trouble updating said pointer per my code so far.

```
class Position {
private:
    static int move;        
    vector<int> pos;        

    Position* start;
    Position* next;

    static int ctorCounter;
    static int dtorCounter;
public:
    Position();
    Position(vector<int>);
    ~Position();

    void setNext(Position*);

    int getCounter();

    Position* afterMove(int);

    bool isDone();

    bool operator==(Position&);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Position&);
};

void Position::setNext(Position* P) {
    Position* cursor = start;   
    if(ctorCounter == 1) {
        start = P;
    }
    else {
        cursor->next = P;
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
}

while(!posQueue.empty()) {
    Position* before = posQueue.front();

    //cout << *before << endl;

    if(before->isDone()) {
        break;
    }

    for(int k = 1; k <= 5; k++) {               
        Position* after = before->afterMove(k);

        if(after != nullptr) {
            P.setNext(after);
            posQueue.push(after);
        }       
    }   
    posQueue.pop();
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

BFS will not help yu to find the shortest path from point to point there are many greedy algorithms like [Kruskal's Minimum Spanning Tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-2-kruskals-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/) and [Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/) to find the shortest path.